# Should we have a "site-building-only" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are some people (like me) who would rather not write any custom code and use contributed modules instead to solve a particular problem at hand. The repository is vast and many modules like Views, Flags and Rules are so versatile that it might be possible to solve the problem without a single line of code, not necessarily in the most efficient way.

Should we have a tag to make clear that the OP is not interested in answers that involve coding?
Maybe "site-building-only" is a bad name and someone will come up with a better one.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this tag is needed, or would be beneficial for the site.

A good question can have multiple correct answers.  Very often, a question can be solved both by custom code (ie, using the Drupal API), and a well-worn contrib module.  In these cases, both answers would benefit future readers.

When you mark an answer as accepted, it really doesn't indicate correct vs incorrect.  Users are supposed to mark the answer that helped them the most as accepted (which does tend to be the best correct answer).

In this specific case, I would phrase the question to say that you prefer a contrib module over custom code.  Users would be free, though, to answer with code.  Having both does happen fairly often.

Comment: Yes @MPD is right because there are lots of good answer for a specific question choice is yours which one you prefer/accepts. That may be the contributed module or custom code.

Comment: I'm only worried about questions that get answered with code and then noone bothers to have a second look and find the answer without code.

Comment: @Turion That's not how a Q+A site operates - you pose a problem that needs to be solved, and people answer it with ways to solve it. Saying "I only want this type of answer" shouldn't actually be part of the question, as this site exists to build a repository of knowledge about Drupal. Solving the person who actually asked the question's problem is secondary to our mission here. It's a nice touch, and almost always happens, but the onus is on making sure the question and answer are relevant to the wider audience, not the person who asked it. It's what fundamentally separates us from forums.

Comment: But other people looking only for, say, a solution without code will come as well and search for answers of that kind. So while I agree that it doesn't make sense to _restrict_ answers to a specific kind, I still hold that it makes sense to want a specific kind of answers _to exist_.

Comment: @Turion We don't make that distinction here - everything in Drupal can be solved either by writing code or installing a custom module, so both are fair game for every question that might apply. We'd never limit an answerer to only solving a problem in a very specific way, that wouldn't be fair on people who _don't_ want to do it that way. Basically it's fine as it is IMO

Comment: And if you're worried about people not answering a question that already has an answer...that's what we have the bounty system for. You can place a bounty on a question, and explicitly state in the message why the current answers won't work for you

Answer (score -2):

I **do** think such tag is needed, and would be beneficial for the site.

Check how many questions there are with "programmatically", which to me is like asking for something like "only by writing some custom code and not use any contributed modules" (the opposite of what this question is about). Questions like "Is there a module for it?" seem like a fairly good fit with "site building only". But such questions seem to not be allowed *anymore* (though there are many old ones out there from the time they were still acceptable). Many of such kinds of questions would probably be a good candidate for using such [site-building-only](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-building-only).

So by introducing a tag like [site-building-only](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-building-only) and also a tag like [programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programmatically), anyone asking a question could right away specify which types of answers they are interested in. And of course, not specifying either tag leaves it open for both types of answers. And by adding either tag to your question, you already indicate the kind of answers that you'll probably not ever going to mark as the accepted answer (no matter if it is correct or incorrect).

Comment: _Questions like "Is there a module for it?" seem like a fairly good fit with "site building only"._ That's the perfect argument for not having this tag. We don't _want_ that sort of question, so we definitely don't want a tag that would apply to questions like it - you've talked your own answer out of any validity with that statement. Tags are also not for indicating whether a certain type of answer will be accepted (we don't care about acceptance, that's just something for the OP). As mentioned above, limiting answers because the OP doesn't want a particular solution is counter-productive...

Comment: ...to everyone else. And we're very much for the current and future masses, not for the individual.